# Why I cannot access ancestor methods from predecessor templated member functions in gcc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc, g++

I have a problem with class member function templates. It seems that gcc is trying to analyze the code semantically too early, without explicit template instantiation.

Let the code speak

A.h (the base class):

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__
class A {
public:
    A* ptr;

    template<class T>
    void method() {
        ((B*) ptr)->invoke();
    }
};
#endif
```

B.h (the ancestor):

```
#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__
#include<cstdio>
class B : public A {
        public:
        void invoke() {
                printf("Method invoked\n");
        }
};
#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include"A.h"
#include"B.h"

int main() {
        A a;
        a.ptr = new B();
        a.method<int>();
}
```

This code compiles and runs fine in Visual Studio 2010 and fails to compile with following error on gcc 4.5:

> In file included from main.cpp:1:0: A.h: In member function ‘void
>   A::method()’: A.h:10:5: error: ‘B’ was not declared in this scope
>   A.h:10:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
>   A.h:10:9: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ptr’

Why is gcc trying to compile code of A::method<>() before any instantiation is requested? Which compiler behaves according to the standard?

**UPDATE:** Now I know that Visual Studio behaves incorrectly. B is not template parameter dependant, so it's not looked up at instantiation, but during parsing of A.h. ([relevant gcc doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Name-lookup.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code *incorrectly* compiles in Visual Studio due to the way templates are processed (basically they are ignored until they get instantiated). In your code, the identifier `B` is not dependent on the template arguments (`T`) and as such, it must be available in the context where the template is defined.

As `B` inherits from `A`, that makes everything even more complicated, as you have a cyclic dependency in the code. I would reconsider the design, and if you consider that it needs to be so, I would merge the two header files into a single one:

```
// merged.h
struct A {
   A* ptr;
   template<class T>
   void method();
};

struct B : public A {
   void invoke() {
      printf("Method invoked\n");
   }
};

template <typename T>
void A::method() {
   ((B*) ptr)->invoke();
}
```

Still, my advice would be to reconsider whether that relantionship makes sense at all, as `method` imposes the restriction that `ptr` **must** be a `B`, and that rings some bells of code smell.

Comment: In the real code it's a bit more complicated than that. A holds vector of A* that may be of type B or other ancestor types. But if this pointer is in fact B* (checked through virtual method String type()) some additional work has to be done.

Comment: @MiKom: Use `dynamic_cast` for checking the type of objects, don't roll your own type methods.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yeah, I know that. Unfortunately, it was not my decision.

Answer (score 0):

ne555 from cplusplus.com forum gave me some neat solution:

new A.h:

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__

class A {
    public:

    A* ptr;

    template<class T>
    void method();
};

#include"B.h"

template<class T>
void A::method(){
    ((B*)ptr)->invoke();
}

#endif
```